Issue related to deploying Azure Virtual Desktop Host Pool Via Terraform
Deploy Azure Virtual Desktop Host Pool Via Terraform
I am writing terraform script to deploy Azure Virtual Desktop Host Pool. When creating host pool  I need to specify session host related configurations such as number of VMs, VM image, local administrator password, Join to EntraID ...etc.
In the terraform provider documentation it only says like this. No other information is provided as well.
vm_template - (Optional) A VM template for session hosts configuration within hostpool. This is a JSON string.
There was no official documentation. So what I did was get ARM template for Azure Virtual Desktop and pass the required values as JSON as according the parameters defined in the ARM template.
resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool" "example" {
  location            = var.rglocation
  resource_group_name = var.rgname
  name                = var.hostpoolname
  validate_environment = false
  preferred_app_group_type = "Desktop"
  type                = "Pooled"
  load_balancer_type  = var.loadbalncealgorithm

  vm_template = <<EOF
  {
    "vmNamePrefix": "${var.vmNamePrefix}",
    "vmLocation": "${var.rglocation}",
    "aadjoin": "true",
    "intune": "false",
    "vmImageType": "Gallery",
    "vmSize": "Standard_B2s",
    "vmNumberOfInstances": "${var.vmcount}",
    "vmDiskType": "StandardSSD_LRS",
    "vmDiskSizeGB": "128",
    "securityType": "TrustedLaunch",
    "existingVnetName": "${var.vnetname}",
    "existingSubnetName": "${var.privsubname}",
    "vmGalleryImageOffer": "windows-10",
    "vmGalleryImagePublisher": "microsoftwindowsdesktop",
    "vmGalleryImageSKU": "win10-21h2-avd-g2",
    "vmAdministratorAccountUsername": "${var.localadminusername}",
    "vmAdministratorAccountPassword": "PasswordForLocalAdmin"
  }
  EOF

  maximum_sessions_allowed = var.sessionllimit
}

However when terraform apply run it shows as successful but does not created the virtual machines as intended. Only host pool was created.
Anyone knows how to solve this issue.

Check this https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-avm-res-desktopvirtualization-hostpool?tab=readme-ov-file#-virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template maybe you need custom gallery image to create multiple vms. based on that it works. not the direct vms like you referred the image @RoshanThamalaka


Issue related to deploying Azure Virtual Desktop Host Pool Via Terraform

The issue that Azure Virtual Desktop Host Pool was created and not the specify session host related configurations such as number of VMs, VM image, local administrator password, Join to EntraID due to fact that there is no other way specify the info of specified info other than gallery image or custom image.
In order to define vm_templete these we need to define the jsoncode and image of the VM with version in the format mentioned.
Demo terraform code:
variable "resource_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the resource group."
}

variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "The Azure location where the resources will be deployed."
}

variable "host_pool_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the Virtual Desktop Host Pool."
}

variable "admin_username" {
  type        = string
  description = "The admin username for the session hosts."
}

variable "admin_password" {
  type        = string
  description = "The admin password for the session hosts."
  sensitive   = true
}

variable "domain_join_username" {
  type        = string
  description = "The username for domain joining."
}

variable "domain_join_password" {
  type        = string
  description = "The password for domain joining."
  sensitive   = true
}

variable "domain_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The domain name for the session hosts."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_load_balancer_type" {
  type        = string
  description = "The load balancer type for the host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_location" {
  type        = string
  description = "The location of the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_resource_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The resource group name of the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_type" {
  type        = string
  description = "The type of the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_custom_rdp_properties" {
  type        = string
  description = "Custom RDP properties for the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_description" {
  type        = string
  description = "Description of the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_friendly_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Friendly name of the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_maximum_sessions_allowed" {
  type        = number
  description = "Maximum sessions allowed for the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_personal_desktop_assignment_type" {
  type        = string
  description = "Personal desktop assignment type for the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_preferred_app_group_type" {
  type        = string
  description = "Preferred app group type for the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_start_vm_on_connect" {
  type        = bool
  description = "Whether to start VM on connect for the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_tags" {
  type        = map(string)
  description = "Tags for the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_validate_environment" {
  type        = bool
  description = "Whether to validate the environment for the virtual desktop host pool."
}

variable "virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template" {
  type = object({
    namePrefix       = string
    count            = number
    vmSize           = string
    useManagedDisks  = bool
    adminUsername    = string
    adminPassword    = string
    osDisk           = object({
      createOption       = string
      caching            = string
      managedDisk        = object({
        storageAccountType = string
      })
    })
    sourceImage      = object({
      publisher      = string
      offer          = string
      sku            = string
      version        = string
    })
    domainJoin       = object({
      domainName     = string
      ouPath         = string
      accountType    = string
      username       = string
      password       = string
    })
    networkProfile   = object({
      networkInterfaces = list(object({
        id = string
      }))
    })
  })
  description = "A VM template for session hosts configuration within hostpool."
}

main.tf:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool" "this" {
  load_balancer_type               = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_load_balancer_type
  location                         = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_location
  name                             = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_name
  resource_group_name              = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  type                             = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_type
  custom_rdp_properties            = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_custom_rdp_properties
  description                      = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_description
  friendly_name                    = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_friendly_name
  maximum_sessions_allowed         = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_maximum_sessions_allowed
  personal_desktop_assignment_type = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_personal_desktop_assignment_type
  preferred_app_group_type         = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_preferred_app_group_type
  start_vm_on_connect              = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_start_vm_on_connect
  tags                             = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_tags
  validate_environment             = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_validate_environment
  vm_template                      = local.vm_template

  depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.example]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "${var.host_pool_name}-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.example]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "${var.host_pool_name}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_network.example]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  count               = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.count
  name                = "${var.host_pool_name}-nic-${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_subnet.example]
}

locals {
  vm_template = jsonencode({
    namePrefix       = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.namePrefix
    count            = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.count
    vmSize           = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.vmSize
    useManagedDisks  = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.useManagedDisks
    adminUsername    = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.adminUsername
    adminPassword    = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.adminPassword
    osDisk           = {
      createOption       = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.osDisk.createOption
      caching            = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.osDisk.caching
      managedDisk        = {
        storageAccountType = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.osDisk.managedDisk.storageAccountType
      }
    }
    sourceImage      = {
      publisher      = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.sourceImage.publisher
      offer          = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.sourceImage.offer
      sku            = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.sourceImage.sku
      version        = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.sourceImage.version
    }
    domainJoin       = {
      domainName     = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.domainJoin.domainName
      ouPath         = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.domainJoin.ouPath
      accountType    = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.domainJoin.accountType
      username       = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.domainJoin.username
      password       = var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_vm_template.domainJoin.password
    }
    networkProfile   = {
      networkInterfaces = [
        {
          id = "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/${var.host_pool_name}-nic-0"
        },
        {
          id = "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${var.virtual_desktop_host_pool_resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/${var.host_pool_name}-nic-1"
        }
      ]
    }
  })
}

Deployment:

Reference:
terraform-azurerm-avm-res-desktopvirtualization-hostpool/main.tf at main · Azure/terraform-azurerm-avm-res-desktopvirtualization-hostpool (github.com)

When specified values to variables this going to failed. Did you VMs get deployed ?
